# Sending a csv through email gives me different result than from a file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a tabular data that I want to send out using email. I can successfully send and receive the email so that is no problem. The problem is the attachment to the email.

I have attached a csv along with it. The csv is created from a Stream Writer. When I open this file, I get a different result that if I created the file from the stream. If I set the stream position to 0 before adding the stream, the csv file would only write 21/30 lines. If I don't reset the posiiton, it would write no lines. When I look at the file that I created, all the entries seems normal and as expected.

Why is that?

```
using (FileStream memstream = File.Create(@"C:\Users\home\Desktop\" + "test.csv"))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memstream))
    {
        data.ForEach(line =>
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", line));
        });

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add("home@local.com");
        message.Subject = "Locations sent to home on " + DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM-dd-yy");
        message.From = new MailAddress("areport@reports.com");

        memstream.Position = 0;
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(memstream, "report.csv");
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("outbound@out.com");
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Had you tried flushing the 'writer' prior to resetting your MemoryStream back to the start?

Comment: Try moving the closing brace of the `using` for the `writer` to before the call to `Send`. After the `ForEach` is probably favourite.

Comment: @jtimperley - No, I have not done that. I just added it and it now works. Now I'm looking at the documentation to see what that does. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, I/O operations are the most costly operation so buffers are used to limit the disk being over utilized by small reads/writes.  Modern partitions store data in at least 64 KB chunks so writing a 100 300 byte lines to a file is more costly than writing 1 3000 byte chunk.  Flushing the stream tells it that you need whatever is in the buffers written now, not when its buffers are full.

Comment: No worries, you took the time to write a well formatted answer that was correct, even if it wasn't your initial thought. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your issues are because it's attempting to send the email before you've closed the file stream. Try sending after  you've closed the file stream.

Comment: In his real scenario this shouldn't matter, it only matters in his example of writing to a file and asking the Attachment to read from that.

Comment: If I send the mail after closing the StreamWriter, it would fail. It says the stream is closed.

Answer (score 0):

As @jtimperley mentioned in the comments your `StreamWriter` is not being Flushed before you send the email so some contents are not written out.

Calling `Flush` on the `writer` should fix it.

```
writer.Flush();
memstream.Position = 0;
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(memstream, "report.csv");
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: That was what I had originally, but whenever the program reaches the client.send(message) line, the sending would fail. Looking into the error it says InnerException, "Cannot access a closed Stream.". The stacktrace would point to the Stream.Read method.

Comment: @bluestring - see my edit jtimperley was right in the comments. My first answer was non-sense.